# Не могу загрузить Rails проект на Git использую Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, git, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Не могу понять в чем проблема, я же зашел в раздел своего проекта rails но все равно пишет, что у меня он пустой репозитарий, кто-то может подробно расписать как на Ubuntu можно правильно, залить проект на Rails в Git? пол дня мучаю( вот код в командной строке.

```
aliz@aliz-z:~/prog$ git clone git@github.com:manka1/ulka.git
Клонирование в «ulka»…
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.118.4' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
warning: Похоже, что вы клонировали пустой репозиторий.
aliz@aliz-z:~/prog$ git config --global user.name
Alez
aliz@aliz-z:~/prog$ git config --global user.email
herofan79@gmail.com
aliz@aliz-z:~/prog$ git init
Переинициализирован существующий репозиторий Git в /home/aliz/prog/.git/
aliz@aliz-z:~/prog$ git status
На ветке master
нечего коммитить, нет изменений в рабочем каталоге
aliz@aliz-z:~/prog$ git add .
aliz@aliz-z:~/prog$
```

Comment: Свежесозданный репозиторий естественно будет пустой. Учебники по git читали?

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать? В репозитории, который вы хотите клонировать, пусто, так что результат вполне ожидаем. Если вы хотите ваш локальный код выгрузить в удалённую репу, то это делается через `git push`. У вас локально создан рельсовый проект? Отредактируйте вопрос и опишите более подробно, чего хотите добиться